# Windows 8 pip install mitmproxy error

Tags: python, windows, mitmproxy

I am trying to install mitmproxy on Windows 8

```
pip install mitmproxy
```

I have installed Python version 2.7.9 and pip version 7.1.2

but I keep getting this error:

```
Collecting mitmproxy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 305, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 250, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 262, in link
    self._link = self._wheel_cache.cached_wheel(link, self.name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 63, in cached_wheel
    self._cache_dir, link, self._format_control, package_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 143, in cached_wheel
    return pip.index.Link(path_to_url(path), trusted=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 456, in path_to_url
    url = urllib_parse.urljoin('file:', urllib_request.pathname2url(path))
  File "c:\python27\lib\nturl2path.py", line 65, in pathname2url
    path = path + '/' + urllib.quote(comp)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1294, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\xe1'
```